# How to do elementwise processing (first int, then pairwise absolute length) to avoid memory problems? (python)

Tags: python, numpy, memory, elementwise-operations

I want to process a big list of `uint` numbers (test1) and I do that i chunks of "length". I need them as `signed int` and then I need it as absolute length from each pait of even and odd values in this list.

But I want to get rid of two problems:

1. it uses a a lot of ram
2. it takes ages!

So how could I make this faster? Any trick? I could also use `numpy`, no problem in doing so.

Thanks in advance!

```
test2 = -127 + test1[i:i+length*2048000*2 + 2048000*2*1]
test3 = (test2[::2]**2 + test2[1::2]**2)**0.5
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'I could also use numpy'?  The expressions you give use `numpy`.  They aren't using Python lists.

Comment: have a look at [numba](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.12.2/tutorial_firststeps.html) or [PyPy](http://pypy.org/) just-in-time compilers

Comment: So do you have 8 bit `uint`'s? Because you're subtracting 127. If that's the case you can (probably) improve a lot by doing `test2 = np.int8(-127) + test1[...]`. Maybe convert `test1` to a `int8` dtype first.

Answer (score 1):

An efficient way is to try to use Numpy functions, e.g:

```
n = 10
ff = np.random.randint(0, 255, n)  # generate some data

ff2 = ff.reshape(n/2, 2)  # new view on ff (only makes copy if needed)
l_ff = np.linalg.norm(ff2, axis=1)  # calculate vector length of each row
```

Note that when modifying an entry in `ff2` then `ff` will change as well and vice versa.

Internally, Numpy stores data as contiguous memory blocks. So there are further methods besides `np.reshape()` to exploit that structure. For efficient conversion of data types, you can try:

```
dd_s = np.arange(-5, 10, dtype=np.int8)
dd_u = dd_s.astype(np.uint8) # conversion from signed to unsigned
```